# Vue is printing my array with [] brackets, why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I want to print out the value in my array, not the `['value']`. It should create a `div='col-md'` box for each index in the array.

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: "#app", 
    data() {
        return {
            step: 1,
            ansPurchaseonly: [
                ['Leasehold', 'Freehold'],
                ['Leasehold', 'Freehold']

            ],
```

HTML template:

```
<div class="row white-boxes justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 h-100 d-table" v-for="(opt, index) in ansPurchaseonly">
    <span>{{ opt }}</span>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Instead I get an output like [ "Leasehold", "Freehold" ] in the html rendered page. I want just:
Leasehold 
Freehold

Comment: `{{ opt.join(' ') }}`

Comment: Vue helpfully JSON encodes objects/arrays you try to output to the template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems you need to run another loop

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 h-100 d-table" v-for="opt in ansPurchaseonly">
 <div v-for="elem in opt">
     <span>{{ elem }}</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it gives me Leasehold Freehold in one span. I want Leasehold in one span and Freehold in another

Comment: that the element in the array isn't?

Comment: I want to treat each value in the array as an iteration. It is being done in a component elsewhere in the code, I want to do the same outside the component. Something like ansPurchaseonly[index -1], I'm not sure

Answer (score 3):

You can use another v-for, because your "opt" is still an array or alternatively you can use join the values like

```
<div class="row white-boxes justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 h-100 d-table" 
       v-for="(opt, index) in ansPurchaseonly">
          <span>{{ opt.join(' ') }}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```